# How to enable library at startup in SAS using command?

Tags: sas

I want to enable my library in SAS at startup but it must be done as a command in the program editor window. I was looking for such an option in SAS Language Reference but without success. Maybe it's a different command?

I've seen the very similar topic but I do not want to use autoexec.sas file or metadata server.

Comment: If you don't want to use `autoexec.sas`, you're going to need to explain why; that's the correct answer to your question.

Comment: Are you just asking how to code a `LIBNAME` statement?

Comment: As of 2012, it appears this is not possible, I don't think it is now either. You can always contact SAS tech support to confirm as well. https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/How-to-create-permanent-libnames-in-my-program/td-p/56359/page/2

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this is either to use `autoexec.sas` or the metadata server.  `autoexec.sas` is created precisely for this purpose (and the metadata server is the server way of doing this).

If for some reason you don't want to do this, you can do the following:

- Always start SAS by opening a program file, which has your libname in it, and running that first thing
- Use Enterprise Guide, which has an autoexec process flow option